# Some JMenus not appearing

Tags: java, windows, swing

I am brand new to code but I am really having fun learning everything. Unfortunately, I have run into an issue that I can't figure out. I am learning how to make a menu bar, menus, and items, but when I run my program it only shows the "file" menu. The help menu appears before I add any menuItems to the file menu, but when I add items, it no longer appears. Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? Thank you all ahead of time.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class Window {

    public static void drawWindow(int HEIGHT, int WIDTH, String TITLE){

        JFrame window = new JFrame(TITLE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(file);
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        file.add(exit);

        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(help);
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
        help.add(about);
```

Comment: You can accept an answer like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/163188).

Answer (score 1):

When I cut and paste the code snippet `window.setVisible(true);` to the end, your contents seem to appear fine.

Check it out for yourself:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JMenu;

import javax.swing.JMenuBar;

import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class Window {

public static void drawWindow(int HEIGHT, int WIDTH, String TITLE) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame(TITLE);

    window.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(file);
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    file.add(exit);

    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(help);
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    help.add(about);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Window().drawWindow(500, 500, "xyz");

}
}
```